# fadeOut first div then fadeIn second div

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadein, fadeout

got a problem i need to do something like a fading banner - one div fading out then second div fading in, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#zeus').fadeOut(1000);
     }, 5000);
    $('#zeuss').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#zeuss').fadeIn(1000);
    }, 6000);
});
```

it works, but after `#zeuss` fades in then it just stays here. I need to do that repeatedly. And please don't offer to use .delay() because im on jquery 1.3.2

**EDIT.**
by default `#zeus` is shown on the page, i want to fade it out then fade in `#zeuss`, then again fade in `#zeus` and then fade out `#zeus` and fade in `#zeuss` etc..

Comment: did you try setInterval(), setTimeout() only happens once, and interval will be called repeatedly

Comment: it's not clear what would you want to achieve: 1. fade out zeus, 2. fade in zeusS, then? wait for... 5 sec? and then? fad out zeusS and then fade in zeus, then wait 5 sec and start from the beginning?

Comment: can you throw an example please? i didn't tryed setInterval()

Comment: @Heihachi Check my answer and [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TtPFc/) and let me know if that is something you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As is often the case, a general and extensible solution is simpler:**

*UPDATE: Took jfriend00's suggestion and moved from multiple timers to completion function to preclude accumulation errors over time.*

```
/**
 * Fade-cycles elements with class 'banner'
 */
$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 3000, fade = 1000; // tweak-able
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;

    setTimeout(cycle, delay); // <-- start

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i%len]).fadeOut(fade, function() {
            $(banners[++i%len]).fadeIn(fade, function() { // mod ftw
                setTimeout(cycle, delay);
            });
        });
    }

});
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/pdsu7/5/) using jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: This is a clever implementation, but do you think the interval timer and the sum of the two animations will stay perfectly in sync with each other forever?  Since we know that in a non-pre-emptive, single threaded system like javascript, timers are not 100% accurate and you have multiple timers going here, it seems unlikely that the interval timer stays completely synced with the timers involved in the animation.  Wouldn't it be much safer to start the next cycle from a completion function rather than from an interval so there could never be some accumulating error?

Comment: @jfriend00 Excellent point, although if `delay` is much larger than `2*fade`, my instincts tell me it won't be a problem. Updated.

Comment: Yeah, if there's extra time after one animation completes before the next one starts, then small accumulations of error wouldn't likely get noticed (I guess it depends upon how long it runs and how long it accumulates error).

Comment: But if the OP wants it to just run continuously with no empty time between animations, then it could easily be noticable.  With fadeIn/fadeOut that use `display:block` and `display: none` at the start/end thus potentially changing the layout of the page at start/end, even a slight overlap between the two can sometimes be noticable if both are in the page at the same time or both hidden at the same time, even if only briefly when that is not intended.

Comment: Thats what exactly i needed! Thanks paislee and others! You saved my da!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to fadeIn and fadeOut 2 different div in an infinite roll. Try below code and let me know,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TtPFc/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isZeuss = false;
    var $zeus = $('#zeus');
    var $zeuss = $('#zeuss');

    $zeuss.hide();

    setTimeout(function () {//<-- Not sure if you want this 5 sec delay in starting the animation
       setInterval(function() {
         var $fadeOutBanner = (isZeuss)?$zeuss:$zeus;
         var $fadeInBanner = (isZeuss)?$zeus:$zeuss;

         $fadeOutBanner.fadeOut(1000, function () {
             $fadeInBanner.fadeIn(1000);
             isZeuss = !isZeuss;
         });
       }, 2000);
     }, 5000); //<-- Not sure if you want this         
});
```

**Edit:** You can increase the `fadeIn/fadeOut` timer or the `setInterval` timer for slower transition.

Comment: This doesn't use completion functions to link all animations to the end of the previous one.  I also don't see a 5 second delay anywhere like the OP had.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated for 5 sec delay. but isn't the 2sec interval is what it needs for cycling. For ex: Lets say zeus is z1 and zeuss is z2. z1 -> fadeOut in 1 sec then z2 fadesIn in 1sec, then setInterval with z2 fadeOut first and then z1 fadesIn for a sec.

Comment: The OP's desired logic isn't completely obvious, but I thought they wanted a 5 second pause with zeus visible on every cycle.  You just have that pause the first time.  Your code assumes that each animation is exactly timed and there is never any variation so your interval can just run every two seconds and assume that two one second animations finishes exactly on time.  Animations aren't that perfect and intervals aren't that perfect.  I thought it was important in my implementation to link the start of the next animation exactly to the completion of the previous one with no error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, without using `.delay()` and linking the start of one animation to the exact completion of the previous animation (without relying on the syncing of timers and animations) and implementing an animation with this repeating sequence:

- zeus visible, zeuss not visible
- Pause 5 sec
- Fade Out zeus
- Fade In zeuss
- Fade Out zeuss
- Fade In zeus
- Repeat

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var z1 = $('#zeus');
    var z2 = $('#zeuss').hide();

    function cycle() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            z1.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                z2.fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    z1.fadeIn(1000, cycle)
                });
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
    cycle();
});
```

If you only want the 5 second pause before the first cycle and not on the following cycles (something that was not completely clear to me in your question), it can be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var z1 = $('#zeus');
    var z2 = $('#zeuss').hide();

    function cycle() {
        z1.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            z2.fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                z1.fadeIn(1000, cycle)
            });
        });
    }
    // start the fadeIn/fadeOut cycling after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(cycle, 5000);
});
```

FYI, the choice of names `zeus` and `zeuss` is horribly confusing.  It is very, very easy to get them confused and very easy to make mistakes in the code.

If you got on a more modern version of jQuery that could use `.delay()`, then it would be a little simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var z1 = $('#zeus');
    var z2 = $('#zeuss').hide();

    function cycle() {
       z1.delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
           z2.fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
               z1.fadeIn(1000, cycle)
           });
       });
    }
    cycle();
});
```

Comment: It's two elements that need to cycle with a delay without using `.delay()` and each animation should be linked to the completion of the previous one.  Feel free to post less complicated code.

Comment: Can you please check my post and let me know if that is something different from what you have (ignoring the timer duration). http://stackoverflow.com/a/10194544/297641

Comment: @Vega - I commented on yours.  It's missing some elements mine has.

Comment: Added an option to my that only does the 5 second pause before the first animation and from then on, it just fades in, fades out alternating between the two objects over and over.

Answer (score 1):

This one starts with one banner visible, then it starts fading out, in, delay, etc...
http://jsfiddle.net/TtPFc/1/

```
#zeus { background-color: blue; color: white; display:none}
#zeuss { background-color: red; color: white; }


<div id="zeus">Zeus Banner</div>
<div id="zeuss">Zeuss Banner</div>
​

$(document).ready(function() {
    var zeus    =  $('#zeus'), 
        zeuss   =  $('#zeuss'),
        forward = true;

    setInterval(function() {
        if (forward) {
           zeus.fadeOut(1000, function() { zeuss.fadeIn(1000); });
        }
        else { 
           zeuss.fadeOut(1000, function() { zeus.fadeIn(1000); });
        }

        forward = !forward;

     }, 5000);
});​
```

Comment: This is a bit of an odd mixture.  You're using completion functions in come cases, but `setInterval()` in other cases and you don't chain the two animations that can be chained directly `zeuss.fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)`.  You could just use all completion functions and no interval.  It looks like you took F. Caledarn's answer and tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make a zeusfadeIn and zeusfadeOut?
  zeusfadeIn do fade in and call zeusfadeOut 
  zeusfadeOut do fade out and call zeusfadeIn