# Jquery fade rotate between 3 divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade rotate between 3 divs, current code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var div1 = $("#apDiv1");
var div2 = $("#apDiv2");

function fade() {
    div1.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    div2.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        // swap in/out
        var temp = div1;
        div1 = div2;
        div2 = temp;
        // start over again
        setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
}

// start the process
fade(); })
```

This works great with 2 divs, but is it possible to insert a 3rd one into the rotation ?

I tried like so:

```
   $(window).load(function(){
var div1 = $("#apDiv1");
var div2 = $("#apDiv2");
var div3 = $("#apDiv3");

function fade() {
    div1.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    div2.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000);
    div3.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    div1.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        // swap in/out
        var 
        temp = div1
        div1 = div2;
        div2 = div3;
        div3 = div1;
        div1 = temp
        // start over again
        setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
}

// start the process
fade(); })
```

But that just skips it / doesn't work at all.

Comment: You're losing/overwriting `div1`, then when it's reassigned to 3, it's back at the 2nd! =] Save `div1` as a temp variable for use again at the end.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10194920/1823841

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gJUPT/3/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be fair if you are going to use more than two divs I would rewrite that function so it will do any amount rather than just three divs

I have assumed that your divs look something like this (I have given them a class of `fade` with the starting one having a class of `current`)

```
<div id="apDiv1" class="fade current"></div>
<div id="apDiv2" class="fade"></div>
<div id="apDiv3" class="fade"></div>
```

given this structure you can use the following jquery within your `window.load`:

```
var divs = $('.fade');

function fade() {
    var current = $('.current');
    var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);

    next.stop().fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });

    current.stop().fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(fade, 2500);
    });
}

fade();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gJUPT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You miss the change with first div:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4ddY/4/

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var div1 = $("#apDiv1");
        var div2 = $("#apDiv2");
        var div3 = $("#apDiv3");

    function fade() {
        div1.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
        div2.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000);
        div3.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000, function() {
            // swap in/out
            var temp= div1;
            div1 = div2;
            div2 = div3;
            div3 = temp;
            // start over again
            setTimeout(fade, 1000);
           });
       }

       // start the process
       fade(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's still only rotating between 2 divs, if I set the div order like this: `<div id="apDiv1"></div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
<div id="apDiv3"></div>`  I can see apdiv1 for a split second between changes, if I set it last it just rotates between `apdiv2` and `apdiv3`, any ideas?

Comment: Well I don't get it, I can see your fiddle is working, I've set it up in the exact same order, but it's still skipping one change (apDiv1 - I can see it for a split second)

Comment: Try copy paste the code I provided. Because I have edited it a little

Comment: I've taken the one from the fiddle. It seems like only apDiv3 is actually staying for the whole second, the other are weird, apDiv2 is maybe a half second, apDiv1 is barely visible before changing to apDiv3.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code save the div1 to temp variable.

```
var temp= div1;
        div1 = div2;
        div2 = div3;
        div3 = div1;
        div1 = temp;
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function(){
      fade();
   });
      function fade() {
           div1.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000, function(){
              $(this).fadeOut(2000);
              div2.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000, function(){
                 $(this).fadeOut(2000);
                  div2.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000, function(){
                       $(this).fadeOut(2000);
                       setTimeout(fade, 2000);
                   });
               });
            });
       }
```

---

You can take the `fade()` function and move it out from doc ready, and call it in doc ready instead.

---

Answer (score 0):

My proposal (available on http://jsfiddle.net/skjHN/):

```
function rotateFade() {
    var toFadeOut = $('[id^=apDiv].current');
    var toFadeIn = $('[id^=apDiv].current + [id^=apDiv]');
    toFadeIn = toFadeIn.length ? toFadeIn : $('[id^=apDiv]:first-child');

    toFadeOut.removeClass('current').fadeOut(2000);
    toFadeIn.addClass('current').fadeIn(2000);

    setTimeout(rotateFade, 1000);
}

// start the process
rotateFade();
```